# seaborn: how to make a tsplot square

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to create a tsplot, where the x and the y axis are the same length. in other words the aspect ratio of the graph should be 1.

this dos not work:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(2, 2)
sns.tsplot(data=df, condition=' ', time='time', value='value', unit=' ', ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could change the aspect ratio of your plots by controlling the [`aspect`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect)
parameter of a `matplotlib` object as shown:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(22)
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

gammas = sns.load_dataset("gammas")
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect=2)  #Use 'equal' to have the same scaling for x and y axes
sns.tsplot(time="timepoint", value="BOLD signal", unit="subject", 
           condition="ROI", data=gammas, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A little more direct is `ax.set_box_aspect(1)`[1](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_box_aspect.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-axes-box-aspect-py)